# How to label a newly created file with "system_u"?

Tags: rhel, selinux

I just created a blank conf file for freetds and noticed that the permissions are wrong:

```
[root@box etc]# touch freetds.conf.new
[root@box etc]# ll -lZ freetds.conf*
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0   freetds.conf
-rw-rw----. root root unconfined_u:object_r:etc_t:s0   freetds.conf.new
```

So I tried:

```
[root@box]# semanage fcontext -a -t system_u /etc/freetds.conf.new
```

But this fails with:

```
ValueError: Type system_u is invalid, must be a file or device type
```

What should I use to change the label from `unconfined_u` to `system_u` on the file freetds.conf.new?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A "temporary" label change is done via the `chcon` command:

```
bash-4.2# touch freetds.conf.new
bash-4.2# ls -lZ freetds.conf.new
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:etc_t:s0   freetds.conf.new
bash-4.2# chcon -t etc_t -u system_u freetds.conf.new 
bash-4.2# ls -lZ freetds.conf.new
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       freetds.conf.new
```

A permanent change would be done via the `semanage` command.  This will add (or modify) a line in `/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.local` which can then be applied with `restorecon`.

So, let's start again with a new file:

```
bash-4.2# rm freetds.conf.new
bash-4.2# touch freetds.conf.new
bash-4.2# ls -lZ freetds.conf.new
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:etc_t:s0   freetds.conf.new
```

We can add a rule for this:

```
bash-4.2# semanage fcontext -a -t etc_t -s system_u /etc/freetds.conf.new
bash-4.2# cat /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.local
# This file is auto-generated by libsemanage
# Do not edit directly.

/etc/freetds.conf.new    system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0
```

This hasn't changed the file yet, though

```
bash-4.2# ls -lZ freetds.conf.new
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:etc_t:s0   freetds.conf.new
```

So now we apply it:

```
bash-4.2# restorecon -vF /etc/freetds.conf.new
restorecon reset /etc/freetds.conf.new context unconfined_u:object_r:etc_t:s0->system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0
bash-4.2# ls -lZ /etc/freetds.conf.new
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       /etc/freetds.conf.new
```

ETA: If you're going to copy the `freetds.conf.new` to `freetds.conf` after you've updated it then I'd probably stick with the `chcon` command; it's easier and the existing ruleset will handle relabeling when it has the right name.  I'd only use the `semanage` form if this is to be the final name.

Answer (score 0):

Selinux user and type are saved inside file attributes. In order to use `semanage` you need to install `policycoreutils-python-utils` package (in RHEL9). Changes made with semanage will be "persistant" the way, that `restorecon` will always mark such named file in such location as defined. When moved and you'll `restorecon` to that file it will be set to type regarding to it's current location (for example admin_home_t for /root/ directory or etc_runtime_t for files within /). It's no more "persistant" in any way for files, which can be moved freely around file system without losing attributes (even copying with `cp -a` copies selinux type and associated user). So using semanage to change file attributes appears to be wrong, because of the structure of /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.local which is ruleset of file paths not linked to real file other than the path itself. `chcon` would change file context without using such a strict paths database and files context changed with it will be persistent across reboots, moving and copying (with -a), just like those labelled from `semanage fcontext`.

So the right answer for most cases would be to use

```
chcon -u USER /path/to/files
```

which marks files according to our needs within file attributes.

Moreover, you need to provide selinux type when changing associated selinux user with semanage. When in need to create such a list of files to make particular files always with same selinux labels with defined user and without changing its type you can use that command:

```
for i in $(find /root/* -type f) ; do semanage fcontext -a -t $(ls -Z $i | awk -F':' '{print $3}') -s SELINUX_USER $i; restorecon -v $i ; done
```

When file is already labelled in such a way with `semange fcontext` you will get an error:

```
ValueError: File context for /root/sth.txy already defined
```

and you should use –m (modify) instead of –a (add):

```
[root@box /]# for i in $(find /root/* -type f) ; do semanage fcontext -m -t $(ls -Z $i | awk -F':' '{print $3}') -s SELINUX_USER $i; restorecon -v $i ; done
```